# R: omi and mar return with xlim-errors

Tags: r, plot, margin, axis

I want to save the image of a plot as png-file; however it cuts off the axis-labels. So I tried leaving a greater margin by setting "omi" and "mar" but it does not seem to work. Adding more pixels does not work either. A smaller value for cex.lab would make the axis visible but unreadably small.

Probably the mistake is silly, yet I cannot figure it out...

```
png(filename = "CarTheftForeigners.png",
width = 1120, height = 646, units = "px", pointsize = 12,
bg = "white", res = NA, family = "", restoreConsole = TRUE,
type = c("windows", "cairo", "cairo-png")
)
plot(Table$Car.Theft,Table$Foreigners, 
 type="p", pch=20, col="red",
 main="Correlation of the Rate of Car Theft and Rate of Foreigners", cex.main=2, 
 xlab="Rate of Car Thefts",
 ylab="Rate of Foreigners", cex.lab=2,
 par(omi=c(1,1,1,1)+0.1))
abline(reg=lm(Foreigners ~ Car.Theft, data=Table),col="blue")
dev.off()
```

No matter what values I add for omi or mar, I always get the error:

```
Fehler in plot.window(...) : ungültiger 'xlim' Wert
```

Which is German and means that the xlim-value is invalid.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The reason for the somewhat cryptic error message is that `plot` was trying to match the value from `par(omi=c(1,1,1,1)+0.1)` to the first unmatched parameter value in `plot.default`'s list of arguments, which was `xlim` in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call `par()` inside `plot`. Try issuing the `par` call before `plot`.

This succeeds:

```
png(filename = "CarTheftForeigners.png",
    width = 1120, height = 646, units = "px", pointsize = 12)
  par(omi=c(1,1,1,1)+0.1)
  plot(1:10, 1:10)
dev.off()
```

This does not:

```
png(filename = "CarTheftForeigners.png",
     width = 1120, height = 646, units = "px", pointsize = 12);
plot(1:10, 1:10 , type="p",  par(omi=c(1,1,1,1)+0.1))
#   Error in plot.window(...) : invalid 'xlim' value
dev.off()
```

However, it you really wanted to use the par call inside plot() you could have named the value as `omi` which would prevent the incorrect positional matching that occurred.

```
png(filename = "CarTheftForeigners.png",
     width = 1120, height = 646, units = "px", pointsize = 12);
   plot(1:10, 1:10 , type="p",  omi = par(omi=c(1,1,1,1)+0.1))
dev.off()
```

Comment: so you mean after the `png(...)` I put the `par(omi=c(1,1,1,1)+0.1)` and then the `plot`?

Comment: Right. Will make explicit.

Comment: Haha, you are awesome! Now the outer margins are perfect! Thank you!